# C# foreach loop thru collection of unknown type

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a generic method that can be called with 2 different object types, TypeA or TypeB. TypeA and TypeB are essentially identical classes except in name only. I am trying to determine how to prevent from having to duplicate the Foreach loop code for each object type. Is this possible ? thanks.

```
public class TypeA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
}

public class TypeB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
}


 private CsvExport GenerateExport<T>(IEnumerable<T> scores)
 {
    CsvExport export = new CsvExport();

    List<TypeA> aList = null;
    List<TypeB> bList = null;

    Type type = scores.GetType();

    if (type.FullName.Contains("TypeA"))
    {
        aList = scores as List<ObjectaModel>;
    }
    else if (type.FullName.Contains("TypeB"))
    {
        bList = scores as List<ObjectbModel>;
    }

    foreach (var dt in aList)
    {
        export.AddRow();
        export["Name"] = dt.Name;
        export["Department"] = dt.Department;
        export["Total "] = dt.Total;
     };

    return export;
}
```

Comment: They should have a common interface maybe? And then collection should be of that interface type?

Comment: A quick and dirty way of achieving this is to just use `dynamic` instead of a generic type.

Comment: The two types have no relation to each other so they *can't* be mixed in the same strongly-typed collection. Having the same property names and types doesn't say anything about their relation. They should inherit from the same interface/base class. This code is redundant though. There's no need to have *two* lists, a single `List<T>` would do. There's not even any reason to check the types. Even if there was, the easy way is with the `is` operator.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Perhaps you could use a library like `CsvHelper` and use its generic methods to write out any collection as a CSV, no matter its type

Comment: As for the current method, all of it could be replaced with `foreach(var dt in scores){...}`. You could use a type constraint to tell the compiler that the types implement a specific interface, eg `GenerateExport<T>(IEnumerable<T> scores) where T:ISomething`. Or you could use reflection to retrieve the names of the public properties and their values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this *particular* case I strongly suggest you delegate the hard work to the [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started) library which you can also obtain from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper) and is used like this...

```
 public void ExportToCsv<T>(string filename, ImmutableArray<T> objects)
 {
    using (var writer = File.CreateText(filename))
    {
        var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
        csv.WriteRecords(objects);
    }
  }
```

The more *general* answer to your question is that you must either have both classes inherit from a common class or interface or you would have to use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to look for an obtain the values of the named properties.

Using a *common interface*...

```
public interface IScore
{
  int HiScore {get;}
}

public class ScrabbleScore : IScore
{
  public int HiScore {get;set;}
}


public class PacManScore : IScore
{
   public int HiScore {get;set;}
}

public void Export<T>(IEnumerable<T> scores) where T: IScore
{
  foreach(var s in scores)
  {
     CvsExport["Hi score"]= s.HiScore;
  }
}
```

Using *reflection*...

```
        var CsvExport = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        foreach(var o in scores)
        {   
            //note that checking the type for each object enables you to have heterogenous lists if you want
            var objectType= o.GetType();
            foreach(var p in objectType.GetProperties())
            {
               var propertyName = p.Name;
               CsvExport[propertyName] = p.GetValue(o).ToString();
            }
        }
```

I would treat the reflection solution as the least favoured of the three.